# Java newbie: How to assign current state of object to another, without establishing reference?

Tags: java, arrays, reference, clone

Once again, I'm looking for a way to bypass this array problem, how? Is there any way other than `clone()`? 
I'm asking because fighting with clone(), protection and implemention stuff didn't work for me...

```
//assuming you have proper class and constructor (point(int x, int y))    
/*
   point 7POINTSARRAY[]=new point[7];
   for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
   {
   7POINTSARRAY[i].x=i;
   7POINTSARRAY[i].y=i;
   }
//This won't work, so...
 */

point B = new point(0,0); // You need this.
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    7POINTSARRAY[i]=B;     // And this. 
    //But I want to read and assign value only,
    //  not establish a reference, so it can work How?
    7POINTSARRAY[i].x=i;
    7POINTSARRAY[i].y=i;
    System.out.println(7POINTSARRAY[i].x);
}
System.out.println(7POINTSARRAY[1].x);
```

Though desired output is A[1].x=1, it's been owerwritten several times, and now A[1].x = 7.

Comment: implement and use a copy constructor. Also read about Java naming conventions. You are almost breaking them all, which makes the code very hard to read. The bad formatting doesn't help, either.

Comment: [Avoid the use of `clone()`; prefer e.g. copy constructors instead.](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=effective+java+clone&source=bl&ots=yYHkQlp3MX&sig=Yx2ur9uQQyWQ2cS45b_-ukysGWc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WPnQUM7SBOeBiwK8i4HABg&ved=0CFsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20clone&f=false)

Comment: Don't be dogmatic with rules or advices, using clone for copying arrays can be useful (and even Joshua Block says that on that chapter: "programmers simply choose never to override the clone method and never to invoke it except, perhaps, to copy arrays"). In any case, the problem here is not instantiate a new Point for each iteration in the loop. A simple constructor solves that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to a create a new `point` for every element of the array if you want them all to reference different objects:

```
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        point B = new point(0,0); // Put this *inside* the loop
        7POINTSARRAY[i]=B;        // Now B is a new instance of point
        7POINTSARRAY[i].x=i;
        7POINTSARRAY[i].y=i;
        System.out.println(7POINTSARRAY[i].x);
    }
    System.out.println(7POINTSARRAY[1].x); // should now print 1
```

I haven't changed your code formatting but improving that will make the above clearer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the line

```
7POINTSARRAY[i]=B
```

which means that each object in 7POINTSARRAY refer (or points) to the same object B.

so when you do inside the loop

```
7POINTSARRAY[i].x=i;
            7POINTSARRAY[i].y=i;
```

you actually always changing B.

You should do instead:

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    7POINTSARRAY[i] = new point(i,i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but Java works only with references for complex objects. You should use and implement `clone()` correctly this can't be the problem. `clone()` is well defined approach.

Typical clone for first level class looks like following

```
    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            A ans = (A) super.clone();

            // do complex stuff

            return ans;

        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }

    }
```

the line

```
A ans = (A) super.clone();
```

does default clone, which includes cloning object but not it's members. You should cascade clone for members. Since `clone()` is a member, it has access to protected members of the parent.

If your parent is `Cloneable` you should write

```
    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        A ans = (A) super.clone();

        // do complex stuff

        return ans;
    }
```

because parent can't throw exception.

For example, if you have point class looking like follows

```
class point {
   public point(double x, double y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
   public double x;
   public double y;
}
```

then you should just fix it in the following way

```
class point implements Cloneable {
   public point(double x, double y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
   public double x;
   public double y;
}
```

to make it cloneable.

Then you will be able to write

```
point a = new point(1,2);
point b = (point) a.clone();
```

and you will get 2 separate copies.